# Terraform conditional output based on passed-in AWS namespace?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
$ terraform -v
Terraform v0.14.6
```

I have a plan that creates different CloudWatch alarms, like this

```
module "rds_high_cpu_alarm" {
  source    = "../modules/cw_alarm"
  namespace = "AWS/RDS"
  statistic = "Average"
  // Other parameters
  ...
}

module "ecs_task_count_alarm" {
  source    = "../modules/cw_alarm"
  namespace = "AWS/ECS"
  statistic = "SampleCount"
  // Other parameters
  ...
}

module "other_aws_alarm" {
  source    = "../modules/cw_alarm"
  namespace = "AWS/OtherNamespace"
  statistic = "OtherStatistic"
}
```

As you can see, the alarms share the same module, `../modules/cw_alarm`, which looks like this, per [aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm)

```
# I want to use this for RDS DB instance high CPU alarm
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "rds_aws_alarm" {
  count      = var.namespace == "AWS/RDS" ? 1 : 0
  alarm_name = var.alarm_name
  namespace  = var.namespace
  statistic  = "Average"
  ...
  dimensions = {
    DBInstanceIdentifier = var.db_instance_id
  }
}

# I want to use this for ECS task count < 1 alarm
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "ecs_aws_alarm" {
  count      = var.namespace == "AWS/ECS" ? 1 : 0
  alarm_name = var.alarm_name
  namespace  = var.namespace
  statistic  = "SampleCount"
  ...
  dimensions = {
    ServiceName = var.servicename
  }
}

# Other alarm resources
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "other_aws_alarm" {
  ...
}
```

How can I set up a generic output to use one of the above resources to put out say the ARN of the alarm?

```
# In pseudo-code
output "aws_alarm_arn" {
  switch var.namespace {
    case "AWS/RDS":
      value = aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.rds_aws_alarm.arm
      break
    case "AWS/ECS":
      value = aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.ecs_aws_alarm.arm
      break
    default:
      value = aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.other_aws_alarm.arm
  }
}
```

**In other words**, how can I output the an alarm ARN based on the created alarm resource? Bear in mind that I can add a lot more alarms than just the 3 I show.

I know I can create different source modules specific to each alarm namespace (which may be a good solution), but humor my geekiness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [conditional expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html):

```
output "aws_alarm_arn" {

  value = (var.namespace == "AWS/RDS" 
          ? aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.rds_aws_alarm.arm
          : (var.namespace == "AWS/ECS"
                ? aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.ecs_aws_alarm.arm
                : aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.other_aws_alarm.arm
            )
          )
}
```

If your alarms are **mutually exclusive**, you can simply the above using [try](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/try.html):

```
output "aws_alarm_arn" {

  value = try(
         aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.rds_aws_alarm[0].arn,
         aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.ecs_aws_alarm[0].arn,
         aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.other_aws_alarm[0].arn)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin. This may be good for just 3 alarm resources, it if that list grows, it could be cumbersome code.

Comment: @ChrisF Yes I agree. But this was your question. You have to redesign your code to avoid the conditions growing, and use `map` preferably for all the possible alarms of yours. Or create modules with the alarms.

Comment: I actually call the above in a `module {}` that's why I want to generalize it.

Comment: @ChrisF I'm confused now. You provided `pseudo-code` of what you want. So can you exactly clarify what is your question, if you don't want the TF equivalent of your `pseudo-code`?

Comment: Is that the most efficient way to do it? Maybe it's the ONLY way to do it?

Comment: @ChrisF I'm thinking now. I think you could re-design code. Just not sure how yet. Do you have many such alarms? Do they differ lots, or only in the namespace, dymention and metric name?

Comment: @ChrisF I updated the answer with simplification.

Comment: Mutually explosive, I like it! :) I will try this indeed.

Comment: @ChrisF How did it go?

Comment: Wow, the `try()` expression worked! Thanks!